# Assembly Finding an element

Tags: assembly, x86

```
section .data
    vec dd 0,2
    len equ ($ - vec) / 4
    msg1 db 'y'
    lenMsg1 equ $ - msg1
    msg2 db 'n'
    lenMsg2 equ $ - msg2
section .bss
    num resb 1
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax,3 
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, num
    mov edx,1
    int 0x80
    
    mov ecx, len
    mov esi, vec
    
check_loop:
    movzx eax, byte [esi]
    inc esi
    add eax, 0
    cmp al, [num]
    jz gasit
    dec ecx
    cmp ecx, 0
    jz negasit
    loop check_loop
    
gasit:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg1
    mov edx, lenMsg1
    int 0x80
    jmp final
negasit:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg2
    mov edx, lenMsg2
    int 0x80

final:
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80
```

This is the code, I'm wondering why does it shows only y and it does not jump to negasit when ecx becomes 0

I don't know how it actually works, i thought this should be a good code. I can only enter 1 digit numbers.

Comment: Does ECX start out even?  If so, then it's the `loop check_loop`  instruction that will make ECX become zero.  Normally if you use `loop`, you don't also inc or dec ECX inside the loop.

Comment: i've removed dec ecx, and the verification for ecx, but now it shows only 'n', it looks like, the code does the loop and then goes to 'negasit', it never compares the numbers in the array with [num] like it should.

Comment: `add eax, 0` is a no-op except for setting FLAGS; probably you wanted `add eax, '0'` to add the ASCII code for the numeral.  Also, your `vec` is 8 bytes long since you used `dd`.  Maybe you want to do 4-byte loads and `add esi,4`.  Or just make it an array of bytes, perhaps `db '0', '2'` of ASCII codes so you can just compare with the input.

Comment: Single-step with a debugger and look at register and/or memory values to see the difference between integers like 0 or 2 and the ASCII codes like `0x30` and `0x32` which represent `'0'` and `'2'`.